# Android orientation handling?

Tags: android, user-interface, screen-orientation

In my AVD, I hit the keyboard keys to switch the orientation of my AVD, and I have a regular main.xml in my res/layout/ folder and another main.xml in my res/layout-land/ folder. The orientation change is handled by my application, but when it is switched back to portrait, the application remains in the landscape view. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're handling the orientation change yourself, you could use `setContentView(R.layout.main)` in the `onConfigchange` method.

Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481793/screen-orientation-landscape-back-to-portrait-not-working), seems like there's a bug in the 2.0 AVD.

Comment: Although I'm using the 2.3 AVD, it seems to have the same issue of not turning back to portrait, even with the built-in apps. I'll just assume my code handles both ways :D